# Backbone.js - default router, get data from URL

Tags: codeigniter, backbone.js

I have a router setup like so:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/agents/:id": "getAgent",
        "/orders/:id": "getOrders",
        "/users/:id": "getUsers",
        '*path':  'defaultRoute'

    },
    getAgent: function(id) {
        ticketList.url = "/index.php/tickets/viewJSON/a"+id;
    },
    getOrders: function(id) {
        ticketList.url = "/index.php/tickets/viewJSON/o"+id;
    },
    getUsers: function(id) {
        ticketList.url = "/index.php/tickets/viewJSON/u"+id;
    },
    defaultRoute: function() {
        //(here needs to be  the code)   
    }

});
```

I'm using codeigniter, so when I visit `/index.php/agents/view/1103` I need to force the `ticketList.url` to be `/index.php/tickets/viewJSON/a1103` - the `a` is taken from `/agent/` (this will change between `user`, `agent` and `order`, `u`,`a` and `o` respectively, and then the ID taken from whatever trails the `view` section of the URL.

Whats the best way to get the default route to take these paramaters from the URL? Literally splitting document.URL?

Comment: What's the URL for the default?

Comment: See my comment to the below answer, hopefully clears some things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to read if you consolidated your three custom routes to one custom route, instead of putting them all in the default.

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "/:resource/:id": "getResource"
    },

    getResource: function(resource, id) {
        ticketList.url = "/index.php/tickets/viewJSON/" + resource[0] + id;
    }
});
```

But note that this will match a lot of different URLs, possibly more than you really want. It might be a better idea to have separate routes for each resource, and just map them all the the same function.

Comment: Cheers for the input, definitely makes sense, however in the future I will be massively extending each function. I guess I could do if statements inside. However - this doesnt actually answer my original question: if I visit `http://mysite.com/index.php/agents/view/1103` (which displays a codeigniter page), I need that to emulate `/index.php/agents/view/1103/#/agents/1103` so the Backbone.js router is triggered. (This is not a single page application, it's a multipage application that i'm using backbone to create tidier code)